# Apache server status does not work with ?auto param

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

What reason could there be for apache's server-status the `?auto` param to result same output as without using `?auto`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that your Apache config has something like this and that
   you're requesting the URL at /server-status?auto

   > ```
   > <Location /server-status>
   > SetHandler server-status 
   > </Location>
   > ```
2. Make sure that no proxy / cache in front of Apache is altering the request. To do this check the access log to make sure the request contains the `?auto` such as `"GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1"`.